# vsCode Selenium 4 upgrade

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upgrade my selenium package to 4. I think 3 is installed, but not 100% sure. When I try to install with pip I get the following.

pip install selenium
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in c:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\program files\python\lib\site-packages (from selenium) (1.26.8)"

Is that even the correct way to update? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was not issuing the command correctly. I was able to upgrade with >pip install selenium==4.0.0.